# Can I create a matrix that will set the state of two variables based on three input variables?

Tags: javascript

I have three javascript boolean that can be true or false;

```
var duplicate
var subTopicClicked
var subTopicSelected
```

Depending on different combinations of these I wish to set the state of the 
following two variabls to true of false:

```
var $scope.modal.disableAddSubTopic;
var $scope.modal.disableDeleteSubTopic;
```

I have tried for a couple of hours to do this with `if else` blocks but 
the combinations are just getting too much and my code now looks a mess. I would include this code in the post but I think doing that would only confuse and I am not looking for anyone to help tidy my code for me.

Instead of a confusing mess of `if else` is there another way that
I can do this by setting up some kind of matrix which will have nine
options and then using this to set the state of my two buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine you mean something like this, where your tree is described as a nest?

```
var matrix = [
    [ // first false
        [ // second false
            [false, false], // third false
            [false, false]  // third true
        ],
        [ // second true
            [false, false], // third false
            [false, false]  // third true
        ]
    ],
    [ // first true
        [ // second false
            [false, false], // third false
            [false, false]  // third true
        ],
        [ // second true
            [false, false], // third false
            [false, false]  // third true
        ]
    ]

];

var a = matrix[+duplicate][+subTopicClicked][+subTopicSelected];
$scope.modal.disableAddSubTopic = a[0];
$scope.modal.disableDeleteSubTopic = a[1];
```

Comment: I am still checking out your solution. Do you feel this will work 100% as it seems a bit simpler than the other solution that is proposed. Thanks

Comment: @SamanthaJ Pros of the other method: fewer _Objects_, you're basically converting a list of _Bool_ to the bits in an _Int_ = fast, Pros of this method: visually the logic is clearer. If your `duplicate`, `subTopicClicked` and `subTopicSelected` are guaranteed to be _Bool_ then every possible path is covered by both of these answers because `2^3 = 8` possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a number out of your three boolean that will be used as index in a lookup array :

```
var index =    ( duplicate        ? 4 : 0 )  
             + ( subTopicClicked  ? 2 : 0 ) 
             + ( subTopicSelected ? 1 : 0 ) ;
```

Your array will have 8 elements, and look like :

```
var  stateArray = [ /*no duplicate*/  /*not clicked*/
                                            /*not selected*/     value1,
                                            /*selected*/         value2,
                                      /*clicked*/
                                            /*not selected*/     value3,
                                            /*selected*/         value4,
                    /*duplicate */   /*not clicked*/
                                            /*not selected*/     value5,
                                            /*selected*/         value6,
                                      /*clicked*/
                                            /*not selected*/     value7,
                                            /*selected*/         value8   ] ;
```

Just wrap the lookup in a function

```
function getState(duplicate, subTopicClicked, subTopicSelected ) {
         var index =    ( duplicate        ? 4 : 0 )  
                      + ( subTopicClicked  ? 2 : 0 ) 
                      + ( subTopicSelected ? 1 : 0 ) ;
         return stateArray[index] ;
}
```

So now if you are using as value an array of two booleans (ex : value1 = [true, false]), set your globals with another function to keep things clean :

```
function setupGlobals(duplicate, subTopicClicked, subTopicSelected ) {
     var valueForThisConfig = getState(duplicate, subTopicClicked, subTopicSelected ) ;
     $scope.modal.disableAddSubTopic    = valueForThisConfig[0] ;
     $scope.modal.disableDeleteSubTopic = valueForThisConfig[1] ; 
}
```

Comment: You can simplify your ternary nest by using bit shifting `(duplicate << 2) + (subTopicClicked << 1) + (subTopicClicked << 0);`, also you need parenthesis, consider how `true ? 1 : 0 + true ? 1 : 0; // 1`

Comment: @PaulS. : Thanks for the parenthesis, that was a bug. For the index building, i prefer that way, which more people will understand i guess.

Comment: Another thing to note is _OP_ is asking for **two** outputs, so you may consider multiplying `index` by `2` at the end, then using `index + 0` and `index + 1` for the choices from an _Array_ with length `16`

Comment: Nope, O.P. has much better keeping this way of doing, with, for instance, value1 = [ subValue1, subValue2 ]; (more readable/easier changes if there's 3 values, or if he uses a {} as value later...)